# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How can I remove the Tealeaf library?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I need to remove the Tealeaf library from my Worklight application in order to have a lighter App (I'm using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 Build id: 20130225-0426 with WorklightStudioPlugin version 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 ).

I have modified my project following these steps:

- In the application-descriptor.xml's Design view I've removed **Optional Features > Analytics**
- Then I've removed the existing Tealeaf folder under native in iPhone’s environment
- Finally I've removed from native\libs the library ***uicandroid.jar*** for Android

Is there any other option/configuration to set?

I receive the error below:

***TLF_configurator.enable was called, but the required Tealeaf libraries are not present in the classpath.***

I haven’t found any details in the official guide. There's only the procedure for adding Tealeaf, not for removing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the Analytics optional feature and rebuild your application/environments, it should have removed everything for you. Just changing the app descriptor XML file is not enough to do so. Did you rebuild your environment after removing the Analytics optional feature?

Also, make sure you are not enabling analytics in your code (by calling WL.Analytics.enable or setting analytics : {enabled : true} in your initOptions.js) and that you are not using the WL.Analytics API in your code.

Comment: I have already checked the WL.Analytics configuration and it is not enabled. Also in my application I don't use any WL.Analytics API.
I have re-build and re-deployed the application, but the behavior is the same: the error about Tealeaf library missing is always thrown. I have also stopped and restarted the server.
Furthermore if I delete the optional feature Analytics from the application-descriptor.xml, the Android and iOs libraries aren't removed automatically.